# Multiple fontsize and fontweight in the same label fig.text

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, title

I have a plot made with `matplotlib`, `gridspec`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.69,8.27))

fig.text(x=0.5, y=0.97, s="'Daily metrics - {Here the 
date}", fontsize=12, ha="center")
fig.text(x=0.5, y=0.93, s= "Total of cases: 23", fontsize=13, 
ha="center")

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=3, ncols=1, height_ratios=[1,1,2], 
left=0.18)
```

I want that the title `"Total of cases: 23"` like this:

`Total of cases: **23**`

and with the number in another font size. How can I combine a different font weight and font size in the same `fig.text`?nIt is important for me not to change `fig.text` to `plt.text`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using latex font rendering in matplotlib. This is activated via the `"text.usetex"` rc parameter, e.g. `plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True`.

Then use `\textbf` for making the number bold. The size of the number can be controlled using the LaTeX style as listed [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles#Font_sizes). I have used `\huge` in my answer. Other options are `\Huge`, `\Large`, `\LARGE` etc.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

fig.text(x=0.5, y=0.97, s="'Daily metrics - {Here the date}", fontsize=12, ha="center")
fig.text(x=0.5, y=0.93, s= r"Total of cases: {{\huge \textbf {23}}}", fontsize=13, ha="center")

plt.plot([1,2,3])
```

[image]

Comment: It crucial to inform people that this is using latex. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks for the comment and changes. I have this command always in the first cell of my Notebook I use for answering so completely forgot to add it :)

Comment: Thanks, @Bazingaa. I get an error when I try your solution, I think it is a common error about latex "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex': 'latex'". 
I have latex installed and when I do: "which pdftex" in the terminal, I get:  /Library/TeX/texbin/pdftex.
I am using a Mac OS 10.14 and Anaconda with Spyder 3.3.3

Comment: @Laura: Ok, my solution assumes you have Latex running on your system. You will have to find out the answer how to solve this error first I think